# C- Crashes while or after free() in remove function

Tags: c

i Wrote a queue in c
and in the function remove when i tring to free the memory of the node the program crashes.
this is the code of the function remove:

```
int RemoveFromQueue(Queue a)
{
int r=0;
printf("test0\n");
if(a->First!=NULL)
{
    printf("test1\n");
    a->Length=a->Length-1;
    r=a->First->DATA;
    NodeQ tmp=a->First;
    printf("test2\n");
    if(tmp==a->Last)
    {
        a->Last=NULL;
    }
    printf("test3\n");
    a->First=a->First->next_Node;
    printf("test4\n");
    free(tmp);
    printf("test5\n");
}
else
{
    return NULL;
    }
    return r;
}
```

the code of queue:

```
struct NodeQ_s{
        int DATA;
        struct NodeQ_s *next_Node;
    };
struct Queue_s{
        int Length;
        NodeQ First;
        NodeQ Last;
    };
```

.h file:

```
typedef struct NodeQ_s *NodeQ;
typedef struct Queue_s *Queue;
```

insert function:

```
void InsertToQueue(Queue a,int b)
{
if(a->First==NULL)
{
    a->Length=1;
    a->First=malloc(sizeof(*(a->First)));
    a->First->DATA=b;
    a->First->next_Node=NULL;
}
else
{
    a->Length=a->Length+1;
    NodeQ tmp=malloc(sizeof((*tmp)));
    tmp->DATA=b;
    if(a->Last==NULL)
    {
        a->Last=tmp;
        a->First->next_Node=a->Last;
    }
    else
    {
        a->Last->next_Node=tmp;
        a->Last=a->Last->next_Node;
        a->Last->next_Node=NULL;
    }
}
}
```

can you tell me what i did wrong or why it crashes?

Comment: You need the whole program to understand what is going wrong. Did you compile with `gcc -Wall -g`? Did you use the debugger `gdb`? Did you use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). You probably have a [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) or a memory leak.

Comment: No, not without at least the struct declaration, and the code that adds things to the queue.

Comment: A crash in `free` usually means that you corrupted the heap some time earlier. As has already been mentioned: time to break out valgrind.

Comment: Even with the edit we cannot tell you what you did wrong. You probably have to find out by yourself.

Comment: i added what you asked for any ideas?

Comment: No, memory corruption is a program-wide bug. You need to hunt it by yourself. BTW, which compiler, which operating system, which compilation flags are you using?

Comment: You handle `Last` inconsistently. Why isn't it set when you insert the first element?

Comment: A general rule of thumb is to initialize the entire `struct` in the routine doing the `malloc`

Comment: i am using windows 7 codeLite ide compiler gnu g++

Comment: didnt understand what did you said about the struct an malloc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is crashing because you're trying to free dynamic memory that doesn't even exist!
`free` takes a pointer to a memory location that it's supposed to deallocate, and you're passing it a `NodeQ` object. You see where the problem lies ?

If `a->First` is a malloc'd pointer you want to free then I guess that you want to point to it, not create a copy of it like you did. Like this:

```
NodeQ *tmp = a->First;
```

Then you can free it.

OfCourse if `a->First` isn't a malloc'd pointer then you don't have call free.

#### Edit

After seeing your struct definition, `First` isn't even a pointer! You can't call malloc for it.

Or you can get what's stored in there using the dereferencing operator like this: `*malloc` and when you're freeing it, get its address, like this: `free(&a->First)`

Comment: a->First is a pointer to NodeQ_s and NodeQ is pointer as well to the same thing

Comment: @user2747228: a `typedef` is not a pointer, plus `a->First` is not even a pointer

Comment: a->First is NodeQ type and using typedef i did that NodeQ is a pointer to NodeQ_s